# Silverlight validation doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, validation

I'm getting troubles validating a field. 
I have a specified a Property named Test with code that throw 
an exception when is less than zero but the validation doesn't work. 
I'm using a web service called from the view. 
I think I forget include something but I don't know what.

Thanks in avance.

**Page:**

```
namespace MonitorizacionIncidencias.Views
{
    public partial class TESTING : Page
    {
        private IncidenciasServiceClient proxy = new IncidenciasServiceClient();

        public TESTING()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            proxy.NextCompleted += new EventHandler<NextCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_NextCompleted);
            proxy.NextAsync(null, 9, false);
        }        

        void proxy_NextCompleted(object sender, NextCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = e.Result;         
        }

    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TEST, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="243,283,0,0" x:Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

**Model:**

```
[DataContract]
public class Incidencia
{

        [DataMember]
        public int TEST
        {
            get
            {
                return test;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                    throw new Exception("TEST EXCP");

                test = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a clearly written question with code & XAML (makes life so much easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing most of it, but you aren't actually handling the [BindingValidationError event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bindingvalidationerror%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) it generates.

**e.g. add this in your XAML (i.e. apply to the textbox or it's parent container):**

```
BindingValidationError="MyBindingValidationError"
```

**and put your actual handling in here:**

```
private void MyBindingValidationError(object sender, 
    ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
    {
        textBox2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    }
    else if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Removed)
    {
        textBox2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
}
```